# Intersect a line with a bicubic Bezier Surface Patch.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, bezier-curve

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4975/calculating-intersections-of-lines-and-algebraic-surfaces) mentions Bezier surfaces, but doesn't go into any detail. How do you going about finding the intersection between a line, $E_{pos} + E_{dir}*t$ and a Bezier surface patch, $P = $

$$\begin{bmatrix}
P_{00} & P_{01} & P_{02} & P_{03} \\
P_{10} & P_{11} & P_{12} & P_{13} \\
P_{20} & P_{21} & P_{22} & P_{23} \\
P_{30} & P_{31} & P_{32} & P_{33}
\end{bmatrix};$$

where a single component curve can be parametrized by $x(u) = $

$$\begin{bmatrix}
u^3 & u^2 & u & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 3 & -3 & 1 \\
3 & -6 & 3 & 0 \\
-3 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
P_{i0_x} \\
P_{i1_x} \\
P_{i2_x} \\
P_{i3_x}
\end{bmatrix},$$

and similarly for $y(u)$ and $z(u)$, and similarly choosing columns rather than rows from the geometry matrix; and the whole surface can be parametrized by $x(u,v) =$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
u^3 & u^2 & u & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 3 & -3 & 1 \\
3 & -6 & 3 & 0 \\
-3 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
P_{00_x} & P_{01_x} & P_{02_x} & P_{03_x} \\
P_{10_x} & P_{11_x} & P_{12_x} & P_{13_x} \\
P_{20_x} & P_{21_x} & P_{22_x} & P_{23_x} \\
P_{30_x} & P_{31_x} & P_{32_x} & P_{33_x}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 3 & -3 & 1 \\
3 & -6 & 3 & 0 \\
-3 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v^3 \\
v^2 \\
v \\
1
\end{bmatrix}?$$

Foley and van Dam, *Fundamentals* mentions an algebraic form, but doesn't show how to get there from the set of points. It is this form that I assume is appropriate for standard root-solving methods, and looks like

$$\begin{matrix}
x(u,v) & = & a_{11}u^3v^3 & + & a_{12}u^3v^2 & + & a_{13}u^3v & + & a_{14}u^3 \\
       & + & a_{21}u^2v^3 & + & a_{22}u^2v^2 & + & a_{23}u^2v & + & a_{24}u^2 \\
       & + & a_{31}uv^3 &   + & a_{32}uv^2 &   + & a_{33}uv &   + & a_{34}u \\
       & + & a_{41}v^3 &    + & a_{42}v^2 &    + & a_{43}v &    + & a_{44}
\end{matrix}$$

But where does the third parameter of the ray come into play?

Comment: You wrote "It is this form that I assume is appropriate for standard root-solving methods". For polynomials in one variable, that's true. The root-finding method will expect you to give it the algebriac coefficients. For problems involving many variables, this is *not* the case. The root-finding package will expect you to give it *functions*, not coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your ray is $\mathbf R(t)$ and your surface patch is $\mathbf S(u,v)$. To find an intersection, you have to find $t,u,v$ such that $\mathbf R(t) = \mathbf S(u,v)$. Both $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf S$ are three-dimensional, and you can consider the $x,y,z$ components of the equation $\mathbf R(t) = \mathbf S(u,v)$ separately. So, you get three equations that (in principle) you can solve to get $t,u,v$. The equations are fairly nasty, and you'll need to use numerical methods.

Your question already has the surface patch equations, partly. Changing the notation a little, you wrote:

$$S_x(u,v) = x(u,v) = \mathbf u \cdot \mathbf B \cdot \mathbf P_x \cdot \mathbf B^T \cdot \mathbf v^T $$

where $\mathbf B$ is the Bezier cubic basis matrix and $\mathbf P_x$ is the matrix containing the $x$-coordinates of the control points of the patch. You can write similar equations for the $y$ and $z$ coordinates of points on the patch:

$$S_y(u,v) = \mathbf u \cdot \mathbf B \cdot \mathbf P_y \cdot \mathbf B^T \cdot \mathbf v^T $$
$$S_z(u,v) = \mathbf u \cdot \mathbf B \cdot \mathbf P_z \cdot \mathbf B^T \cdot \mathbf v^T $$

The ray equation can be written as $x$, $y$, $z$ components, too. If the ray in vector form is $\mathbf R(t) = \mathbf A + t\mathbf W$, then we can write components:
$$R_x(t) = A_x + tW_x$$
$$R_y(t) = A_y + tW_y$$
$$R_z(t) = A_z + tW_z$$

The three equations you need to solve are:

$$S_x(u,v) - R_x(t) = 0$$
$$S_y(u,v) - R_y(t) = 0$$
$$S_z(u,v) - R_z(t) = 0$$

There is no need to transform these equations into algebraic form. You just define

$$f_x(u,v,t) = S_x(u,v) - R_x(t) = 0$$
$$f_y(u,v,t) = S_y(u,v) - R_y(t) = 0$$
$$f_z(u,v,t) = S_z(u,v) - R_z(t) = 0$$

and you feed the three equations $f_x(u,v,t) = 0$, $f_y(u,v,t) = 0$, $f_z(u,v,t) = 0$ into your favorite numerical root finder.

You seem to want to find the algebraic coefficients -- the coefficients of $u^3v^3$, $u^3v^2$, and so on. You don't need to do this. It doesn't help. The numerical root finder doesn't care. You feed it *functions*, not algebraic coefficients.

There actually are more clever ways to intersect a ray and a (bicubic) Bezier patch. One relevant paper is: J. T. Kajiya "Ray Tracing Parametric Patches" Computer Graphics (Proc. SIGGRAPH 82), Vol. 16, No. 3, July 1982, pp. 245-254. He shows that a ray and a bicubic patch can be intersected by solving a single equation of degree 18. Of course, this has to be done numerically, too. I think this approach is probably more trouble than it's worth, and I would recommend the approach outlined above.

Also, take a look at [this e-book](http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node91.html).

Comment: I've got a reprint of that paper in the *IEEE Tutorial: Image Synthesis*. But I have difficulty seeing where to plug-in the points. ... Everybody says they're nasty equations! But no one's published them.

Comment: I added the equations into my answer

Comment: Thank you. It's a much stronger presentation, now. I know I'm being stubborn but I really think I can do something with these equations. I'll probably accept your answer in the end. But it would, in a sense, mean *defeat*, you know?

Comment: You will get 3 equations of degree 3 in the variables $u$, $v$, and $t$. The best you'll be able to do is eliminate $u$ and $v$. The Kajiya paper shows you how to do this. You'll be left with an equation of degree 18 in $t$.

Comment: Oh. I was looking at the wrong paper. SIGGRAPH 82. Got it now.

Comment: An idea occurred to me. Just for kicks, try this: take *any* three random equations that have $u$ and $v$ with powers up to 3, and linear in $t$, and see if you can do anything with them. The point is -- it doesn't matter whether these equations came from a ray-patch interection problem. Or, looking at it another way, *any* set of equations comes from *some* ray-patch intersection problem. After you try this exercise, I'm hoping that you will agree that it's not a very promising approach.

Comment: I had a suggestion in comp.lang.postscript to rotate the whole space so the ray coincides with the x-axis. That appears to reduce it to $S_x(u,v)-t=0$, $S_y(u,v)=0$, and $S_z(u,v)=0$. Then I think I can use Kajiya's approach to solve for u and v separately. I don't really understand his presentation of Bezout's Theorem, but Wikipedia suggests I can skip that and use a Sylvester Matrix. ... I took a sample patch from the dataset and computed the algebraic terms. Even without doing a rotation, there are lots of zeros in the coefficients, which I find promising.

Comment: Yes, rotating is useful. Then, you have to eliminate u and v. There are many ways to do this elimination (or "implicitization" as it's called). They are mostly based on various types of resultants. If you look up "resultant" and "implicitization" you'll find lots of stuff. This is all 19th century algebraic geometry that has been resurrected by the CAGD research crowd.

Comment: This really does appear to be *the right answer* both popularly and pragmatically, so I accept. I'm not giving up, but it's going to take me some time to understand Kajiya. First surprise is his use of homogeneous coordinates, so I'm going back to Maxwell for background, and I found a pdf of *Modern Higher Algebra*, by George Salmon, 1885, from wikipedia.

Comment: OK. Go for it. Good luck. You may well find it easier to understand the more modern accounts of implicitization (rather than Maxwell, Salmon, and Kajiya). People like Ron Goldman and Tom Sederberg have written quite a lot about the subject.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check those out. I also stumbled across this: [Implicitization and parametrization of quadratic and cubic
surfaces by μ-bases](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~dengjs/files/papers/47%20mu23.pdf) which looks pertinent.